# Adding properties to DLL after it's been built

Tags: c#, .net, dll, properties, versioning

I have a set of C# DLLs that have already been built--they've gone through the process of setting the version numbers in AssemblyInfo.cs, they've been formally built by our configuration management team, and they've been archived off where they belong so we don't lose the built DLLs.

Now I have to take a collection of these DLLs and package them up into a couple umbrellas, and these umbrellas can have different versions. For example:

```
Collection1 v1.0  Collection1 v1.1  Collection2 v1.0
----------------  ----------------  ----------------
MyDll1.dll v1.0   MyDll1.dll v1.0   MyDll1.dll v1.0
MyDll2.dll v1.1   MyDll2.dll v1.2   MyDll4.dll v1.0
MyDll3.dll v1.2   MyDll3.dll v1.2   MyDll5.dll v1.1
```

Looking through each DLL's properties, I already see its usual fields, including File version and Product version set to its respective version number.

What I would like to do is to capture the collection name and version number somewhere in order to show which collection it belonged to when it was packaged up. Again, the DLLs are already built, so I can't add anything to AssemblyInfo.cs now.

Ideally, this would be another property that shows up on the DLL's Details tab, and it would be something that I can inject into a DLL using some tool, but I'm not familiar with any Windows API calls that can add/modify these properties.

Keep in mind this is for internal releases of these DLLs so we can keep track of what we have installed ourselves during development; the ones that will be packaged and released "for real" would be the pristine ones formally built and won't have any properties added into them.

EDIT: Third-party tools will be difficult to use; if it doesn't come with Windows or Visual Studio, then it would be strongly preferred if it's something that can be written very quickly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ILMerge tool provided by Microsoft: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Just create a DLL containing all custom assembly-level attributes you want to merge. Then run ILMerge specifying MyDll.dll as a primary assembly and your DLL with custom attributes as a secondary one. Don't forget to specify /copyattrs flag.

Full ILMerge documentation can be found here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.doc

If your input assembly is signed, you also have an option to provide .snk file, so that your output assembly will be signed as well.

Another option is to use a combination of ILdasm/ILasm tools, which seem to be part of the SDK. But it requires a little bit more efforts because you need to modify IL code in between.

Comment: Ooh. Sorry I forgot to mention third-party tools will be difficult to get approved. I updated the original question to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft hardly qualifies as a _third party_.

Comment: Alright. Additional tools that have not yet been put on the list of approved tools, don't come preinstalled with Windows, and don't come on the CD/DVD with Visual Studio will be difficult to get approved.